# Sequelize autoIncrement and SQLite

Tags: sqlite, sequelize.js

Just getting started with Sequelize and trying to setup an auto increment column on an SQLite database.  The migration looks like this:

```
return queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  ...
```

But looking at the generated table schema gives this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Users` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ...
```

What happened to the auto-increment?

---

Follow up: just tried this on a different machine (both Windows machines btw) and it seems to be working fine.  I guess something is out of date on the other machine.

Comment: Recommended reading: [ROWIDs and the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid). The column becomes an alias for the rowid.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it: turned out to be an older version of node and/or npm.  Updated to latest, trashed node_modules, re-ran npm install and the table's being generated correctly now.